# Using Access databases in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

How would I use a Microsoft Access (`.accdb`) database in C# (console application, not web asp.net)? From what I've read, I'll need to use `ADO.NET`, but I'm really at a loss as to how to do this in a C# console application. In PHP with `MySQL`, I'd be looking for `mysqli_construct` Could anyone point me towards a tutorial or documentation that would help me with that? I'm trying to use it as a way to store and access data for my **non-web, non ASP.NET** application, if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Comment: ADO.NET is ADO.NET, regardless of whether it's inside ASP.NET or not.  You can still use web examples, just ignore anything related to HTTP request and response.

Comment: thanks, @R0MANARMY, it's just that I wasn't sure, and wanted to make sure you guys had as much information as was needed ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this [walkthrough for using ADO.NET to edit an Access database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx).

Now while that example is using a web application, don't worry, the classes being used are still applicable for a console application as well.

The main classes you will need to use are:

- [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/588b9ffa.aspx)
- [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h37f2yxh.aspx)
- [OleDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stkwe6zb.aspx)

The documentation of the classes above all have code samples that are console app examples.

Below is a code snippet for use in a console app (remember to add the: `using System.Data.OleDb;`

```
string connectionString = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    @"Data Source=C:\path\to\your\database.mdb;" +
    @"User Id=;Password=;";

string queryString = "SELECT Foo FROM Bar";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Also, just noticed you explicitly said an .accdb database. For this grab the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255). The provider in the connection string would then need to be changed to: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` (see notes at that link for more info).

Answer (score 3):

Just use `System.OleDb`. Here is a small class that I use

First of all, **place the database fle inside App_Data**

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseName.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**App_Code/DataAccess.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public class DataAccess
{


    #region "Public Methods"

    public static DataTable GetTableFromQuery(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, CommandType commandType)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection()) {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn)) {
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                if (parameters != null) {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters) {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                    }
                }
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

    public static object GetSingleObjectFromQuery(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, CommandType commandType)
    {
        object value = null;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection()) {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn)) {
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                if (parameters != null) {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters) {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                    }
                }
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        value = reader.GetValue(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, CommandType commandType)
    {
        int value = 1;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = GetConnection()) {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn)) {
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                if (parameters != null) {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters) {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                    }
                }
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Private Methods"

    private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString;
        return new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

---

Now call it from page like

```
var myTable = DataAccess.GetTableFromQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName", null, CommandType.Text);
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the set of braces on that first `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [OLEDB Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) there are some simple examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1449/OLE-DB-First-steps).